# sails.js and how to hook into passport.js

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I created a custom policy, and from there I want to get some additional info from twitter passport.js for example.

I have no idea how to hook into the passport instance.

Comment: Passport.js can be used to set some kind of session variable to make sure the user is authenticated, after which you can just check the session state in your policy. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to get the latest twitter displayname of a user for example. But i want to do it manually.

Comment: Also doing this to figure out how to work with node modules

Comment: Still new to node modules

Comment: Take a look at this project https://github.com/stefanbuck/sails-social-auth-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Sails 101 passport implementation example: https://github.com/sails101/using-passport/blob/master/api/hooks/passport/index.js